cpprest not close connection immediately after response
I use cpprestsdk to handle my connection in the project as:
pplx::task<web::http::http_response> validate_license(web::http::client::http_client client, const std::string license_key){
web::http::http_request req;
...
return client.request(req);
}

after I process response I cann't close connection immediately
validate_license(client, key)
        .then([&](http_response res)
            {...})
        .wait();

I tried to see documentation but no help!
